# Python 3.3.0: How to output a variable onto a .txt file

Tags: python, string, file-io

Basically i have a variable called final which looks like this:

```
final = (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,)
```

All the variables are strings generated from sperate lists. It is in a loop so final is given a value then printed and this continues 10 times.
I am trying to output the variable "final" into a word document called answer.txt on my desktop.
I have little coding experiance and cannot find a way to achieve this,
Any help appreciated,
Thanks

```
Z
J
V
C
F

H
Y
L
3
6

M
O
C
5
A
```

Comment: Please put a sample of the output of `print(final)`. copy and paste it into your question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open(r'C:\Users\MyUsername\Desktop\answer.txt', 'a') as fd:
    print(' '.join(final), file=fd, end='\n')
```

where '`'.join(final)` puts a space between each string in `final`. you can replace `' '` with `'\n'` if you want a newline there, or any other string.

The flag for `open` should be `'a'` in your case, since you want to continue adding lines to the file. Another option would be to put the line `with open(...) as fd` outside the printing loop, if possible.

The `end` argument to `print` controls what string willbe printed after each line. the default is `'\n'`, which means a new line, but it can be anything, including an empty string `''`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Elazar but the code did not work, when i open up the file it is blank. any ideas?

Comment: @jackfazz98 It works on my machine, and should work on yours. what exactly does final contain? I understood something like `['hello', 'world']`. Am I wrong? Note that 'answer.txt' is assumed to be the *full* path to the file.

Comment: The variable Final contains several randomly generated variables joined together, basically its a random code generator but i want the result outputted to the text file. Would it be easier for me to e-mail you the code as im not very good at explaining? Thanks again

Comment: @jackfazz98 You can post the code in your original question, or in a site like http://pastie.org/ (and add a link to it in your question).

Comment: IF you look at the other answer and the comments you will see that i now have it printing but it is only printing once (instead of 30) and is printing vertically.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to fix this for me. works perfectly now!